# How to create gif image with different text formats in php with background image?

Tags: php

Is this possible to create a gif image with various text font,style,formats and alignment having background image in php?

For example I have a background image like
[image]

And an image which I want to insert on background image is

[image]

And the output gif image should look like
[image]

I tried the code for this

```
<?php
// Create a new image instance
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 250);
$img = imagecreatefrompng('back.png');
// Make the background white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 300, 250, 0xEFEFEF);

// Draw a text string on the image

imagestring($im, 20,20, 40, 'Heading1', 0x000000);
imagecopymerge($img, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 250, 70);
// Output the image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($img,'test.gif');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't give the output as desired and I want to add more content to the background image as I shown in output image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this design:

[image]

You can use this code:

```
<?php
// Create a new image instance
$img = imagecreatefrompng('back.png');

// Draw a text string on the image
//  imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )
imagestring($img, 5, 20, 30, 'Heading1', 0x000000);
imagestring($img, 3, 180, 30, 'Heading 2 test desc', 0x000000);

imagestring($img, 3, 20, 80, 'Text info 3', 0xFF0000);   //red
imagestring($img, 1, 180, 80, 'Demonstration text', 0x000000);

imagestring($img, 5, 400, 170, 'Price here', 0xFF0000);   //red

$im = imagecreatefrompng('plane.png'); //load pic 2
imagecopymerge($img, $im, 0, 130, 0, 0, 165, 71, 70);
imagedestroy($im);

// Output the image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

The `imagestring()` function is limited to a built in, rather ugly font, and with size option of only 1 to 5. You can use another function for TTF fonts instead as described below.

To change the font you need to provide your own TTF format fonts, place them in the same folder as the script and replace the `imagestring()` function to this one instead. The parameters is very similar and it should be trivial for you to replace that code yourself. Here's the link explaining how to use `imagettftext()`-function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php